# Crontab append remotely

Tags: unix

I would like append entries to crontab on a remote server.
Something like this.

```
for host in $hosts
do
ssh $host echo "5,10,15,20 05,35 8-20 * * * /myhome/myscript" crontab_file
done
```

problem is i do not know the name of the crontab file to which the line 
needs to be appended with

Answer (score 0):

You should *not* edit crontab file directly, use always `crontab -e` (why? read [this](http://www.unix.com/unix-advanced-expert-users/50062-where-crontab-file-stored.html)). But you could create a simple text file with your script and cut&paste into crontab.

Comment: just like copying any other text from a file to another